# Who created the dome and why?

Tags: under-the-dome

I'm looking for spoilers for the Stephen King novel *Under the Dome* and the TV show, if available.

**Who created the dome and why?**

Comment: The book does not spoil the TV series, and vice versa.  Other than a title, the most basic element of the premise, and the names of some of the major characters, they are different stories after the first couple of episodes.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried to watch the TV series but I couldn't make myself care about the characters.  As for trying to choke down another 1000 page Stephen King novel, no thanks, I'm full.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> In the book, Aliens.  Never very much explained, but, basically, some kind of Leather-headed Alien Children, playing with the Earth the way human kids might play with an Anthill.  They are seen by several of the protagonists when they touch the artifact that is generating the dome.

To quote from the [Stephen King Wiki](http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/Under_the_Dome):

> They not only conclude that the device was put in place by extraterrestrial "leatherheads" (so named for their appearance), but that specifically they are juveniles who have set up the Dome as a cruel form of entertainment, a sort of ant farm used to capture sentient beings and allow their captors to view everything that happens inside.

I haven't seen the TV series, so I can't speak to that :)

Comment: I'm so glad I didn't bother finishing the book. What a total cop-out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6TRVXG4kQE

Comment: I'll be honest -- it SOUNDS that way, but so do a lot of Stephen King endings.. The book is a lot less about the reason / resolution, and more about the experience of the people under the dome.  The dome itself is just a narrative vehicle to basically stick them on a desert island that no-one else can reach.  (It's basically 'Lord of the Flies' with adults, and Stephen King's perception of how humans act, what their motives are, etc.)

Comment: I'm convinced that King stopped writing stories years ago and is basically ghosting novels.

Comment: I would have to be trapped UNDER A DOME, before I would read it... King may have been great once, now he is just phoning this stuff in...

Comment: To add to the mini discussion, I've been an avid fan of King for years, and while I agree a lot of his stories don't have the most original of premises, I feel his skill in writing comes from his personal form of presentation of the ideas, be they new ideas or re-used ones. I felt Under the Dome was one of his best novels. It's not always about the main idea, but the little ones that add together to make up the big one with King a lot of the time. His personal style to scribe human nature is the real horror, not the monster.

Comment: @ender - Exactly; as I said above -- the Dome was just a vehicle for the story -- an excuse for the setting to exist.  Personally, I almost wish he had ended it with it never explained (and possibly not removed), but I think he caved slightly to the pressure of people wanting closure.

Comment: @Thaddeus I don't recommend his latest book which was an outing in a detective mystery (The Mercedes Killer) - Under The Dome was a masterpiece compared to that. Such a pity because his time travel book about the JFK assassination was pretty good.

Comment: @Thaddeus actually to me this book was very reminiscent of classic King... a strong sense of building to a climax which ends up disappointing. It's the one aspect of his writing which _always_ annoys me. He just can't write an ending!

Comment: I personally felt that the ending of Season 1 was quite a cop out - it felt like a bad cliff hanger.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the ending of the novel, but if I read a 1000+ page novel and enjoy it all except for the last chapter, I wouldn't call it a bad book.

Comment: @Valorum have you read Bag of Bones yet?

Comment: @Seamusthedog - tbh, I stopped reading King years ago. At this point I'm fairly convinced that he's just employing a series of ghostwriters to churn out a predictable stream of books in the style he's employed before.

Answer (score 12):

The TV Series and the novel have already [diverged quite significantly](http://stephenking.com/promo/utd_on_tv/letter.html), and there's every indication that it will keep doing so.

In the novels, the dome's origin is eventually exposed as:

> Alien kids playing with Earth, the same way human children might play with an ant farm or hamster cage.

In the TV show, it's becoming clear that the dome has a far more significant purpose, but we have no idea where it came from or who (if anyone) is "operating" it. Given that it's Stephen King, it wouldn't be surprising if aliens were involved, but I highly doubt it will be as straightforward (and largely anti-climactic) as the book.

Comment: Someone/something is definitely operating it.  They made contact in the Season 1 finale, but didn't really explain much.

Comment: Those aliens are called the *screenwriters*. And the purpose is to get view on a "reality show" they are producing.

Answer (score 2):

In the TV series, [the dome exists to protect the egg that converts other species into The Kinship, an alien species, and to trap suitable subjects within the space to be converted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Dome_(TV_series)#Plot_synopsis).

> The Kinship is an alien species that can take over any living person and control its actions. Another species had sought to take over The Kinship's world, during an event known as "The Great Destruction". To survive, The Kinship abandoned their own world, hoping to live on another life-supporting planet. They used an egg inside a meteor to transport themselves across the galaxy, hoping the meteor would crash on another inhabited planet.
>
> In 1980, The Kinship's meteor crashed in the center of Chester's Mill. Teenagers Melanie, Pauline, Sam and Lyle found the meteor in the middle of the woods. As they approached it, four hand prints glowed, one on each side of the meteor. Each of them placed his or her hand on the meteor, which triggered it to open, revealing a glowing pink egg. Attracted by the egg, Melanie picked it up. However, Lyle pushed her into the meteor, and she died.
>
> Had she stayed alive longer, Melanie would have been infected by The Kinship, and a dome (a device that traps and protects life forms inside it) would have lowered over the town, while a mini-dome descended over the egg (an energy source), and Melanie and her friends, as the first life forms to have come into contact with the egg, would have been pulled underground, into a large cave which forms instantly. There, they would have been able to view the town from within a large "Queen-size" cocoon. But since she died, it didn't happen then. Panicking, Melanie's friends buried her and the alien egg, swearing never to talk about the incident again.

The events of the series were kicked off when another intact egg was found and activated, this time without any of the activators immediately being killed.

> Now, in 2013, two archaeologists, Christine and Eva, search for an intact egg, which they believe to be located in Chester's Mill. They work for a large energy company called "Aktaion," which, in the past, studied other eggs that crashed to earth. The other eggs had broken when they'd crashed, so, when the eggs were touched, domes did not come down.
>
> Christine and Eva find the intact egg. As Christine holds it, the infection process begins, and The Kinship beings transfer into her, as she screams in pain. Once the process is complete, a large pink explosion occurs, and the dome lowers around them, a mini-dome descending over the egg. Christine and Eva get sucked into a large cave, which appears below them, and get cocooned.